# Converting the do notation to bind notation

Tags: haskell, monads

How do I convert the below Haskell do notation to the bind `(>>=)` notation?

```
rev2lines :: IO ()
rev2lines = do line1 <- getLine
               line2 <- getLine
               putStrLn (reverse line2)
               putStrLn (reverse line1)
```

I am a Haskell beginner with decent knowledge and I tried something like

```
getLine >>= (\line1 -> getLine >>= (\line2 -> putStrLn $ reverse(line2)))
```

but I am not able to include the print statement for the other line i.e. line1. Kindly help me to understand this concept properly.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile (indentation error).

Comment: @melpomene, the code that I tried works fine for one out of two strings. Am I not getting what you are saying?

Comment: `prog.hs:3:12: error: parse error on input ‘line2’` - https://ideone.com/dLe2de

Comment: @melpomene fixed the indentation. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're almost there: you need to use `>>`.

```
getLine >>= (\line1 -> 
getLine >>= (\line2 -> 
putStrLn (reverse line2) >>
putStrLn (reverse line1)
))
```

Note that `>> ...` is equivalent to `>>= (\_ -> ...)`, so you can also use that if you prefer.

Similarly, your block

```
 do line1 <- getLine
    line2 <- getLine
    putStrLn (reverse line2)
    putStrLn (reverse line1)
```

is equivalent to

```
 do line1 <- getLine
    line2 <- getLine
    _ <- putStrLn (reverse line2)
    putStrLn (reverse line1)
```

Essentially, any entry in the block (but the last one) which has no explicit `<-` uses `>>` (or, if you prefer, has an implicit `_ <-` in front).

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you meant

```
rev2lines = do
           line1 <- getLine
           line2 <- getLine
           putStrLn (reverse line2)
           putStrLn (reverse line1)
```

the desugaring looks like

```
rev2lines =
           getLine >>= \line1 ->
           getLine >>= \line2 ->
           putStrLn (reverse line2) >>
           putStrLn (reverse line1)
```

which parses as

```
rev2lines =
    getLine >>= (
        \line1 -> getLine >>= (
            \line2 -> (putStrLn (reverse line2)) >> (putStrLn (reverse line1))))
```

Comment: thanks a ton for the quick and correct answer. can you please explain why did we need to use the **>>** operator?

Answer (score 6):

The `putStrLn` has type `IO ()`, so we can construct a dummy variable `_` as a way to obtain the *unit type* `()` and so keep processing, so:

```
rev2lines = getLine >>=
                (\line1 -> getLine >>=
                    (\line2 -> putStrLn (reverse line2) >>=
                        (\_ -> putStrLn (reverse line1))
                    )
                )
```

Since the pattern `f >>= \_ -> g` occurs quite often, there is the [**`(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62-) operator such that `f >> g` is semantically the same as `f >>= (\_ -> g)`, so a shorter form is:

```
rev2lines = getLine >>=
                (\line1 -> getLine >>=
                    (\line2 -> putStrLn (reverse line2) >>
                        (putStrLn (reverse line1))
                    )
                )
```